# What is the inner cover of the winter shoes called in English?

Tags: word-request, terminology, image-identification

In Europe — in some countries, especially in the eastern Europe there are very common shoes which covered inside with something that makes it warm and comfortable in the time of the winter, cold and snow. What is the general name for this inner cover?

(I have tried to find the term in my language and I didn't find. I also looked for it on a visual dictionary and no results. I'm even not sure if the using of the word "cover" is correct in this context, but that's the way that I can express myself)

Can I call it: upholstery?

(This knowledge can be useful for example when going to a shoe shop and I would like to ask for such shoes and how to name them correctly and understandably)

[image]

Comment: As someone who lives in San Diego, I have no idea what you are talking about.  What is this "winter" of which you speak?  :)

Comment: "Upholstery" isn't appropriate here because upholstery is 1. padded, and 2. covers an exterior surface.

Comment: "lined shoes" shows immediately correct pictures on Google.

Answer (score 46):

This is called a [lining](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lining):

> material that lines or that is used to line especially the inner surface of something (as a garment)<sup>(MW)</sup>

You would ask questions such as:

> What are those boots lined with?
>
> Is the lining removable?
>
> Do you have any gloves with fur lining?

Comment: Or a 'liner', at least as I have heard it.

Comment: "A lining" is usually attached (e.g. sewn); "a liner" is usually detached (e.g. loose, or buttoned /zipped). Thus you usually remove a liner, but tear / rip out a lining.

Answer (score 16):

*Lining*.

Usually any substance which covers the interior surface of a garment is said to *line* the garment and will be called a *lining*.

So you will have silk-lined dresses and fur-lined coats and fleece-lined shoes.

Answer (score 4):

It may be called any of the following

- lining
- liner
- innerboot

Comment: "Innerboot" would refer specifically to a boot-shaped liner, made of foam, that would look like a small boot when taken out of the shoe.

Answer (score -5):

Where I grew up we called that the *flance.* Not sure where it comes from.

Comment: Where did you grow up?

Comment: I feel your downvote pain Rachel, but at least you can't go down from 1! Where I grew up (in AFRICA, m'kay people) we called it the *tongue*, but I dare not add that as an answer!!

Comment: @Jongosi. I, a native English-speaker from Ireland, would say that the *tongue* is a different part of the boot altogether: it sits below the laces.

Comment: @TRiG I think I got confused... I thought that's what the question is referring to! I see now that the OP does in fact mean the *lining*!